# Download Sharepoint Online files via Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, web

I've been handed a project, where our marketing dept produces images and each workstation & laptop need to download those images on startup or login.  (wallpaper folder, screen saver images, etc etc)

I'd like to use Sharepoint Online to store a publicly accessible (no login required) folder with the images, and then use Powershell to grab the contents.

Every example that I find requires a snapin or module for this.

Does anyone know of a straight-forward way of vanilla Powershell copying the contents of a publicly available SO folder to local disk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick update - This was not feasible using Sharepoint Online.  It does not allow tools like Invoke-WebRequest to perform any type of directory search and intelligently download files.

We ended up using a standard nginx server for this project.